# Why is my python socket client not sending events to my node.js server?

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, python-socketio

## Question

I have a simple express server (just showing the socket, the route is default):

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('identify')
  
  socket.on('identity', (data) => {
    activeUsers.push(data['name'])
    socket.name = data['name']
    console.log('Connection from ' + socket.name)
  });

  io.on('disconnect', (data) => {
    activeUsers.splice(indexOf(socket.name))
    console.log(socket.name + ' disconnected.')
  })
  
  io.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data['message'])
  });
});
```

I then wrote a python client, and connection worked fine:

```
@io.event
def connect():
  print('connected')

@io.on("identify")
def identity():
  io.emit("identity", {"name": "isaiah08"})
```

However, when i changed identify to be:

```
@io.on("identify")
def identity():
  io.emit("identity", {"name": "isaiah08"})
  io.emit("message", {"message": "I WILL EAT YOU"})
```

It did not log the message. Why is this?

## Note

Yes, I created a socket in the / route:

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

And I am connection to the right website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't registering the event handler for `message` correctly on your server, so the message is arriving, but your message handler to receive it isn't configured properly.

Change this:

```
  io.on('disconnect', (data) => {
    activeUsers.splice(indexOf(socket.name))
    console.log(socket.name + ' disconnected.')
  })
  
  io.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data['message'])
  });
```

to this:

```
  socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
    activeUsers.splice(indexOf(socket.name))
    console.log(socket.name + ' disconnected.')
  })
  
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data['message'])
  });
```

These messages come to the `socket`, not to the `io` object.  You wrote it correctly with the `"identify"` message, but not with these other two messages.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!